# Is an empty function called at all in optimised code?

Tags: c++, optimization, performance, runtime

If the TEST macro is not defined, I would like to know whether there is a performance difference in these two pieces of code:

```
void Func1(int a) {
   // ...
}

#ifdef TEST
Func1(123);
#endif
```

and:

```
void Func2(int a) {
#ifdef TEST
    // ...
#endif
}

Func2(123);
```

With `TEST` not defined, `Func2` would become an empty function that the compiler should not call at all, isn't it?

Comment: Pro tip: look at your compiler's assembly output and see for yourself.

Comment: Following on from @Martinho's comment: if you're using `gcc` then the `-S` flag will instruct the compiler to output assembler so you can see for your self what's going on.  Try it with different optimisation `-O` settings.

Comment: I believe not.  In C/C++, the program is first compiled and then linked.  These two steps are basically independent.  In addition, the compilation of two different functions are also basically independent.  Thus, except for inline functions, at the compile time, when the function call is to be compiled, it does not know that the function to be called is an empty function. It just follow the call convention (to prepare the parameters, if any) to generate intermediate code for the function call.  In the link step, it actually modifies the intermediate code to fix down the call address.

Comment: @RobinHsu: where you say "except for inline functions", you should say "except for inlined functions". With modern optimizing compilers you can assume that whether or not a function call gets inlined is more or less independent of whether the function is marked `inline`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Well, for inline functions I actually refers to those written inside header file.  Since in header files, it is fully included before it is used.  Thus the compiler may know it's empty before it reaches the line calling the empty function.  Otherwise, the optimization can only happen in the link time. This means at compile time, it must generate two choices of codes, one for normal codes, and the other for the opt-out codes.  The choice is then delegated to the linker.  Yes, I admit in this way, the compiler/linker can opt-out empty functions.

Comment: I'd be really disappointed if they weren't the same in any modern compiler if I'd requested the function be inlined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It pretty much comes down to whether that particular call to `Func2` is inlined or not. If it is, then an optimizing compiler ought to be able to make an inlined call to an empty function the same as not calling it at all. If it isn't inlined, then it's called and returns immediately.

As long as the function definition is available in the TU containing the call to `Func2`, there's no obvious reason it won't be inlined.

This all relies on the fact that `123` is a literal, so evaluating the arguments of your call has no side-effects. The args have to be evaluated even if the function call has no effect, so:

```
int i = 0;

/* 'i' is incremented, even if the call is optimized out */
Func2(++i);

/* 'i' is not incremented when 'TEST' is undefined */
#ifdef TEST
Func1(++i);
#endif
```

Comment: don't forget Link Time Optimization :)

Comment: @Matthieu: I hadn't forgotten, I *deliberately* didn't say anything about what happens when the function definition isn't in the TU ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Optimizations are generally compiler-specific. The language standard does not, AFAIK, make any statements about what should and what should not be optimized away. (Although I admit I haven't read the language specification itself.)

Each compiler has its own set of options by which to enable / disable specific optimization steps.

So the answer is a definite "it depends", and "you would have to check yourself to be sure".

(However, I'd be quite surprised if a halfway decent optimizer would leave such a construct unoptimized.)

Comment: The standard does tell things that *should not* be optimized (like say, accesses to volatile variables). Sometimes it also tells what optimizations *can* be done (like copy ellision).

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: I never think of `volatile` when talking about optimization, as in my mind they're two different things somehow. You are right, of course. But on the level of this question, C99 doesn't make any statements, and I would be surprised if C++ did.

Comment: @DevSolar: The goal of optimizations is to transform code while keeping the same _observable_ behavior. `volatile` is explicitly defined as observable behavior, so they are closely related. (Other observable behavior is calling specific library functions).